# Cannot connect over SSL using PostgreSQL JDBC driver

Tags: postgresql, ssl, jdbc

I am trying to connect a database over SSL(namely TLSv1.3).

When tested with `psql`, it connects over TLSv1.3.

With JDBC driver as below, the connection is not secured by SSL at all for some reason.

(confirmed this by executing `select * from pg_stat_ssl;`)

```
      val props = new Properties()
      props.setProperty("user", "postgres")
      props.setProperty("password", "example")
      props.setProperty("ssl", "true")
      props.setProperty("sslmode", "allow")
      props.setProperty("sslfactory", "org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory")
      DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/", props)
```

What would be the cause of this problem?

PostgreSQL JDBC driver versions: 42.2.5/42.2.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `sslmode` to `allow`, the client will prefer non-encrypted connections. Change the setting to `require` or `prefer`.